# onResume() not pulling info from onPause()

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm making this small text based rpg game where users can choose their name, race, class, etc...

I have one activity where the user types the name they want to use, then selects the race, class from spinners.

Then when they hit the Create character button, it all transfers over to the next activity. That works perfectly.

The problem is on the onPause event when it saves the data. The onResume() method just doesn't work? The views just show up blank.

Heres the selected code:

(This is where the data is pulled from the other activity)

```
String Name = getIntent().getStringExtra("strName");
    textViewStrName.setText(Name);

    String Race = getIntent().getStringExtra("strRace");
    textViewStrRace.setText(Race);

    String Class = getIntent().getStringExtra("strClass");
    textViewStrClass.setText(Class);
```

(This is the onPause() method)

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.clear();
    String strName = textViewStrName.getText().toString();
    String strRace = textViewStrRace.getText().toString();
    String strClass = textViewStrClass.getText().toString();
    editor.putString("strName", strName);
    editor.putString("strRace", strRace);
    editor.putString("strClass", strClass);
editor.commit();
```

(This is the onResume() method)

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    TextView textViewStrName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStrName);
    TextView textViewStrRace = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStrRace);
    TextView textViewStrClass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewStrClass);
    TextView textViewStrAlliance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStrAlliance);


        textViewStrName.setText(preferences.getString("strName", null));
        textViewStrRace.setText(preferences.getString("strRace", null));
        textViewStrClass.setText(preferences.getString("strClass", null));
        textViewStrAlliance.setText(preferences.getString("strAlliance",
                null));
```

I'm not getting any errors when I run the app.

Comment: Try calling `super.onResume();` at the end.

Comment: it's like it doesn't even call the method

Comment: Can you put the full code to the activity?

Comment: Best implementation should works on startActivityForResult() in your Activity A.

Comment: please do check for `null` because some String stuff does not throw NPE if it encounters null, it just shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a SharedPreferences storage between activities, use getSharedPreferences() instead of getPreferences. See details [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#GetSharedPreferences).

Also don't forget to call `editor.commit()` after making changes.

Comment: yep i did that. Just didn't put that in the description. Edited